# Referencing a vector in a R sqldf statement

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I have a SQLDF statement that references a dataframe but I also want it to reference a vector that is not part of the dataframe as shown below.

```
sqldf("select count(*) from carddata where new_user_indicator == 'Y' & loyalty_threshold >  average_loyalty_threshold")
```

average_loyalty_threshold is a stand-alone vector that is calculated separately and is not part of the data frame.

How can I reference the stand-alone vector in a sqldf where clause.

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what it is you want providing a reproducible example including all inputs and library statements and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

```
library(sqldf)

carddata = data.frame(new_user_indicator = c('N','N','Y','Y','Y'),
                      loyalty_threshold = c(1,1,5,3,1))
```

And your goal is to use another vector with a single value to select all entities of `carddata` whose loyalty threshold is above that value, you can use the following:

```
# create a dataframe from average_loyalty_threshold so that sqldf will see it as a table
average_loyalty_threshold = data.frame(threshold = 2)

sqldf("select count(*)
      from carddata
      where new_user_indicator == 'Y'
      and loyalty_threshold > (select * from average_loyalty_threshold)")

#returns

  count(*)
1        2
```

With the `(select * from average_loyalty_threshold)` you can pick out that single value that you are looking for.

However there is simpler way:

```
average_loyalty_threshold = 2

fn$sqldf("select count(*)
  from carddata
  where new_user_indicator == 'Y'
  and loyalty_threshold > `average_loyalty_threshold`")

#returns

  count(*)
1        2
```

Here, I passed the value of loyalty threshold straight into the query.

You could also use `sprintf()` for this text pasting but as others pointed out in the comment, `fn$` is the recommend way to reference outside variables.

Comment: The normal way to do text substitution with sqldf is to use `fn$`.  See `?fn` and the examples on the sqldf home page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Comment: Hi @niczky12, I wasn't familiar with sprintf in the context of R. I found this article: http://rfunction.com/archives/2279 that shows another great example.  I'm also going to check out fn$. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the tip. However `fn$` method throws an error with variable names that have underscores in them. I think this is still a work in progress. Sprintf seems more stable.

Comment: It allows only \w characters in the variable name and _ is not a \w character.  This seems like a reasonable choice to me consistent with regular expression character sets.  Consider that if an underscore did not terminate a variable name then you could not use $ to generate commonly desired things like create the name `var_2016_04_06` using `var_$year_$month_$day`.  Note that `fn$` also allows an arbitrary R expression within backquotes so you are not really lijmited in any way.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks. I figured it out and updated my answer. Thanks for showing me this method.